# How can I Reverse routing and fingerprinting for public assets in non-scala page

Tags: java, playframework

The official sample is in scala [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Assets#Reverse-routing-and-fingerprinting-for-public-assets) , but my project use java and plain html.

So I don't know how to translate this line

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("assets/css/app.css")">` 
to a plain html file.

Comment: Why are you using plain html? If you use the Play framework, it shouldn't be a problem to use the reverse router with java within you html template files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly: you can't.

You need to put your raw HTML files in the `views` folder and change their names from `foo.html` to `foo.scala.html`, then you can write simple action which will render proper templates by reflection.

You can use them even if they doesn't contain any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Having a default `Play` configuration for routes:

```
GET /assets/*file controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

If your file resides under following directory:

- public

  - assets

    - css

      - app.css

You can translate the link to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/assets/css/app.css">
```

Basically `public` directory is replaced with `assets`. Rest stays the same.
Keep in mind, if you amend `Assets` configuration in `routes`, your links might become dead.